# Laravel URL Generator With Angular JS Varible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.3

I am making an application with Angular JS as frond end and Laravel as back end.

I having a list of master data table view and a delete and edit options.

```
<a class="resedit btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{URL::route('edit_repair_category',[[category.id]])}}/"><i class="icon-note"></i></a>
<a title="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow($event,category.id,'{{URL::route('delete_repair_category')}}',currentPage)" class=" btn btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

Above I am generating URL of Edit page with Laravel URL Generator, But I want to pass the ID of the master data to fetch the data from controller.

I am using [[ ]] for Angular JS bindings.

```
URL::route('edit_repair_category',[[category.id]])
```

Now I got the exception **Use of undefined constant category - assumed 'category'**

Routes.

```
Route::get('edit-repair-category/{id}', ['as' => 'edit_repair_category', 'uses' => 'RepairCategoryController@editRepairCategory']);
```

Is there any possibilities ?

Comment: can you please let us know that, what is the output of href ?

Comment: Its showing Fatal error. There is no way to inspect the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're mixing `javascript` and `PHP`.

The `PHP` portion of you code is going to be processed on the server and then passed to the browser where the `javascript` is then going to be processed, so as far as `PHP` is concerned you are trying to use a constant.

Since `category.id` is just going on the end of the url you should be able to do something like:

```
<a class="resedit btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{ URL::route('edit_repair_category', null) }}/@{{category.id}}"><i class="icon-note"></i></a>
```

`null` is being used here to prevent an error being thrown.

The `@` before `{{category.id}}` just tells blade to treat this like a normal string and not to do anything with it (the `@` symbol will be remove by blade).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Errror.... Missing required parameters for [Route: edit_repair_category]

Comment: @JpDevs Of course! Sorry about that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not working. your answer url('edit-repair-category') is not perfect. its just making the url that I gave. I having a prefix for my routes and that is not taking here.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. You should be able to just pass null to the route.

Comment: Hi, How can I send two or more variables with this. Once I checked not working properly.

Comment: @JpDevs As your question above goes slightly outside of the scope of this one would you be able to create a new question with the above issue?